# Why does DateTime.AddDays round to nearest millisecond?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am dividing two doubles in .NET and using the result object to work out an end date from a start date by calling (dtStart is predefined):

```
var dValue = 1500.0/8400.0;
var dtEnd = dtStart.AddDays(dValue);
```

After inspecting dtEnd I found that the result was only accurate to the nearest millisecond. After looking it up I found that .AddMilliseconds etc. all round the number and TimeSpan.FromDays does a similar thing. I was wondering if there was a reason why this rounding was done since it seems like the only way to get the correct value here is to use .AddTicks?

For reference .AddDays calls (where MillisPerDay = 86400000)

```
public DateTime AddDays(double value) 
{
    return Add(value, MillisPerDay);
}
```

which calls

```
private DateTime Add(double value, int scale) 
{
    long millis = (long)(value * scale + (value >= 0? 0.5: -0.5));
    if (millis <= -MaxMillis || millis >= MaxMillis) 
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_AddValue"));
    return AddTicks(millis * TicksPerMillisecond);
}
```

Comment: That one cost my quite a bit of debugging time. Before writing some audio related code I calculated that the precision of both double and `TimeSpan` is enough to uniquely identify a particular sample. And then the stupid `FromSeconds` function decided to round to milliseconds...

Answer (score 2):

Edit: After thinking things over, I now realize the first version of my answer was wrong.

Here are the comments in Microsoft's source code:

```
// Returns the DateTime resulting from adding a fractional number of
// xxxxs to this DateTime. The result is computed by rounding the
// fractional number of xxxxs given by value to the nearest
// millisecond, and adding that interval to this DateTime. The
// value argument is permitted to be negative.
```

These comments appear on five different AddXxxxs(double value) methods, where Xxxx = Days, Hours, Milliseconds, Minutes and Seconds.

Note that this is only for the methods that accept a floating point value. (And one may question whether or not it is a good idea to involve floating point values in date calculations - but that's a topic for another day.)

Now, as the OP correctly points out, these five methods all call this method:

```
// Returns the DateTime resulting from adding a fractional number of
// time units to this DateTime.
private DateTime Add(double value, int scale) {
    long millis = (long)(value * scale + (value >= 0? 0.5: -0.5));
    if (millis <= -MaxMillis || millis >= MaxMillis) 
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_AddValue"));
    return AddTicks(millis * TicksPerMillisecond);
}
```

So what is being done is that the value being added to the DateTime is rounded to the nearest number of millisecond before being added. But not the result - only the value being added (or subtracted).

This is actually documented, for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx "The value parameter is rounded to the nearest millisecond."

Why it does this I don't know. Maybe the programmers figured that if you're using floating point values you should be aware that your values are typically not completely accurate. Or maybe they want to simulate to some degree Java-style times, which are based on milliseconds.

Comment: I whish the original coder of the DateTime implementation would answer.
If they didn't scale to milliseconds but directly to the number of ticks per day, I think we would get rounding errors when adding more than 1042.5 days. This number comes from the max integer range that can be represented exactly by a double, 2^53 -1, divided by TicksPerDay. Microsoft uses 100-ns resolution, so TicksPerDay is 24*60*60*1000*1000*100.
So, my guess is rounding to milliseconds makes the behavior a bit more easier to predict.